# What are some plausible patterns that could develop in alien languages?

Tags: phonology, semantics, semiotics

I ask the question here and not in world formation because as an aspiring author I know that linguistics and other such specialists in the study of language 
treat the notion of language in a very particular way, such that defining a language in a formal sense and according to given criteria is much more delicate in some cases than it might first seem, and certainly so when to those outside the discipline.

In my question, I mean to highlight the fact that our human languages have patterns, such as individual words, or morphemes and, of course sounds or phonemes, etc. There are also rules, commonly enough, that regulate how those items are to be used alongside one another, and still other common features such as tense, aspect, mode, case, gender, and so forth. Hence, when I highlight the fact that our human languages have patterns, I do so knowing full well that such is not necessarily the same at all should it evolve in a different kind of intelligence but that plausibly so, it could at least be entertained that such languages have certain patterns before others or certain more advanced patterns therein, necessarily.

Ethologists might tell us a great deal about the communication of elephants or whales or dolphins or monkeys or even dogs and cats that would seem to lend credibility to the notion that languages might well develop along very different principles that we could nonetheless understand analytically how ever unintelligible they may otherwise be to us. Of course, I agree right off the bat that a given alien language would be totally hypothetical, but I don't ask for an exhaustive description of any one alien language, much less an entire list of them, since of course it's just speculation. I only mean to ask what your personal take may be regarding potential linguistic patterns that might seem useless for us, or that were once common in certain languages but have since died, or that are used in computers but not human languages; or still in other systems, as it were. In the same way that we know that if an intelligent* life form is to exist and to succeed as a species, being ambulatory or having hands or eyes will typically ensure their longterm survival versus having no hands, no feet, and no capacity to fly or swim, likewise we can speculate that certain features of language may be present where others would be less likely or would necessitate certain kinds of intelligence, physiology, society, etc.

Perhaps an advanced (alien) intelligence could well develop a language, as is often our means of distinguishing our intelligence from that of animals, but incorporate different aspects of reality that aren't necessarily present or that are not emphasized in many successful human languages today. So, what could such a principle like tense or aspect or case be that is not at once present in any human language that, at the same time, merits inclusion because of its possible or probable linguistic utility for that species? Of course, you may not know every single human language and every one of its patterns, that is true. An accomplishment that would be! But you nonetheless know tense and gender, suffixes and sentences; and how successful these patterns are across all or most all (modern) human languages.

It is true that if I put myself in your place, I imagine that some of you will want to deflect my question, since unless we know the physiology of the alien intelligence, there is little in the way of speculation that can be supported since whatever the assumed language, we have no way of knowing if it operates through sound, signs only, or still some other medium or media. This would be true and a good point on your part, so to it I'll respond that the language have enough communicative and used signs or symbols to be compared to a system so vast and so developed that were it to occur in our case, it would be considered a language or near language. I might even say that so long as it can be shared and used as a means to communicate among hundreds or thousands or better, millions of intelligent life forms, then to me that qualifies as a candidate of language.

Of course, that still leaves open the notion of mere visual signs that might be communicated through body language, or a phonology so many times removed from our own that no visual representation need ever occur. The phonetics might be so many times different that only by calling it language could it be considered such. I agree, again, that these are indeed possible. I only seek to know what some principle patterns might be; the kinds of language that could (possibly) evolve, in your mind.

What do you have to offer if you were to answer that maybe an alien language would operate in such and such a way? Maybe if there were lots of little clicks, the clicks would be distinguishable because... Or maybe if there were lots of signs, the signs would be read and gestured rather than spoken because... Or maybe any such languages would never be able to advance very far because without other media, they would lack critical aspects of linguistic depth, utility, recognition, and the cognitive conveniences that we might not immediately consider when pondering the question, etc. For example, how far could sign language go... for billions of people? Could billions of people communicate with sign language only, or through sound only? Clearly accent and no spelling or written system would very much complicate if not impair the higher reaches of thought, such as jurisprudence, mathematics, philosophy, and so forth: and so essentially, for language to be advanced, mustn't it be visual? Patterns!

I recognize that my question leaves a lot to be desired, but please give it a go. Maybe some really interesting ideas will come out of your answer that other people would never have considered and will find really, really interesting!

*Intelligence here being literal and used in the connotatively standard sense

Thank you :)

Comment: Hi, it seems that the four or so people who treated the question as too vague perhaps failed to understand its point. Nothing about a language pattern is vague. Words are a kind of pattern across languages, as is grammar, syntax, tense, etc. Yes, of course it is true that any answer would be speculative, but that doesn't detract from the plausibility of any proposed pattern. For example, the patterns that we see in human languages do something so well that they spread or are in some cases perhaps inherent to language, as Chomsky argues of course in hypotheses like generative grammar.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many answers to the question, none of them right or wrong, just maybe more popular vs. less popular. You might start by looking at actual [alien languages in the literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_language_in_science_fiction), such as The Hero's Tongue, the fart language of the Yherjak, smoke signal language, whatever that is that the Buggers transmit, or the metaphor language of the Tamarians ("Dharma and Greg at the beach!!").

Typically, authors focus on the "phonology" i.e. the means of transmission, such as sound, smell, something tactile, and direct mind implanting. You obviously have to tailor the mode of transmission to the physiology (is any) of the beings, so a language with lots of clicks is not very likely for pure energy beings. This may explain why the guy from Vhoorl is called [kʟ̝̊ʊlʔ.ɬuː] – he is a slave to his octopus-dragon physiology. Often, authors leave the audience wondering how a civilization whose language is just short bursts of "ack" and "rack" could fly to Earth and take over.

Very little attention is paid to structural details, and usually alien languages are portrayed as being infinitely logical and compact, or infinitely complicated and nuanced. It is likely that many of these languages are preloaded so no learning is required. To design an alien "language", you have first decide what kind of beings these are, and what the "language" is for. For example, maybe these beasts automatically turn colors in response to their emotional state, and use sine waves to convey propositional content. That would affect their sound-based system. We have to decide if the creatures have free will, or not. If they do, can they lie? Do they use shorthand abbreviations like "dog", or do they use longer descriptions like "being with four legs and fur, which likes to chase the smaller beings with four legs, fur, and needle-like claws"? The possibilities are infinite.
And so on.